# Load a Paraview state file from a pv server

Tags: paraview

I have activated a `pvserver` (Ubuntu), then created an SSH tunnel in my client (Win 10), and connected paraview to the server.

Then in paraview, the menu for *File* -> *Open* shows the filesystem of the server.
But *File* -> *Load state* shows the client filesystem.

**Is there a way to load a Paraview state file from the server?**

I would rather do it straightforwardly.
I guess I could map a network drive to the share in the server, so the client sees it.
That would be somewhat cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, no.

The server manipulate the data, so *data* files to load (and store) are on *server side*.

Then you perform action in the client. A state file contains instructions to replicate those actions *from the client*. So state files are on client side.

Note that a state file can refer to data files. Those data files need to be on server side.